# How can I add a thin frame around rawimage border?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now the image color/s mix with the background skybox color/s.
That is why I want to add some frame around the image either the image have Textured or if the image is white empty without any texture.

[image: RawImage]

Comment: Child object with anchors on each 4 corner, then frame image.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a background panel (`Image`) as parent of the `RawImage`

```
Canvas
|--Image
   |--RawImage
```

(=> raw image is drawn on top of the image) and make the `RawImage` use fully stretched anchoring (also see [`RectTransform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/class-RectTransform.html) and [Basic Layout](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIBasicLayout.html))

```
Anchor
    Min 0 0
    Max 1 1
```

then you can define exactly how big in pixels (Screenspace overlay) or Units (world space) the border should be by setting e.g.

```
Left 10
Right 10
Top 10
Bottom 10
```

> Positions of the rectangle's edges relative to their anchors. **This can be thought of as padding inside the rectangle defined by the anchors**. Shown in place of Pos and Width/Height when the anchors are separated (see below). To access these options click the square Anchor Presets box at the top left of the RectTransform component.

The color of the frame is then simply the color of the `Image` component -> could even have an additional texture